# Set/update cookie on every page load

Tags: drupal

I have a small snippet of code that does some work on a cookie on every page load.

(It's for affiliate tracking if you want to know why)

Where do I put this so it runs **every** every time a drupal page is loaded

Answer (score 1):

api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_boot